# Resurrection of the Dead in the "Torah"

Tags: talmud-gemara, tanach, resurrection-of-the-dead

In the Bavli, Berakhot 15b, R' Tavi explains Proverbs 30:15-16 in such a way that it implies a resurrection of the dead, and concludes that this is a response to those who say that there is no reference to the resurrection of the dead in the Torah. But is Proverbs part of the Torah?

If we consider the book of Proverbs to be part of the Torah, then surely we can also consider the books of Isaiah and Daniel to be part of the Torah, and they mention the resurrection of the dead explicitly:

Isaiah 26:19, "Your dead shall live, their corpses shall rise. O dwellers in the dust, awake and sing for joy!"

Daniel 12:2, "Many of those who sleep in the dust of the earth shall awake, some to everlasting life, and some to shame and everlasting contempt."

If references like these can be considered "part of the Torah", then why do we need to find clever interpretations of non-explicit passages in order to answer those who claim that the Torah contains no reference to the resurrection of the dead? And if the books of Isaiah and Daniel are not to be considered "part of the Torah", why is the book of Proverbs?

Comment: dont understand the question. who said this is the only hint of the ressurection in tanach?

Comment: @ray You're right - it clearly isn't! My question is: if there are explicit references to the resurrection in Tanakh (and there are), then why do we need something non-explicit like this to answer those who don't think there's a reference to it in the Torah? Why not quote Daniel or Isaiah, which are more obvious? And if that's because Daniel and Isaiah are not in the Torah, can we say that Proverbs is?

Comment: because this was R.Tavi's chidush.

Comment: @ray Sorry - which bit was his chiddush? That Proverbs is "Torah" but Daniel and Isaiah aren't? Or that the passages in Isaiah and Daniel that I quoted are not actually references to the resurrection of the dead? Or just that the cryptic passage from Proverbs is a *better* reference to the resurrection than those ones? Or something else?

Comment: he deduced a new additional reference to the resurrection. that was his chidush

Comment: @ray I see - instead of, "here's an answer to those who say...", "here's an[other] answer to those who say..."? That's a possibility! (You want to put it in an answer?)

Comment: sure. posted...

Comment: more clearly ask "if clear references of it exist in prophets then why do some says there is no resurrection mentioned in torah?"

Comment: @Michael16 `if clear references of it exist in prophets then why do some says there is no resurrection mentioned in torah` That is a totally different question! (Presumably they didn't accept the authority of Prophets, or interpreted it non-literally. Note that that doesn't address our question, for whatever shortcomings are found in Prophets, the shortcomings of Proverbs re correspondingly greater)

Comment: Just saw this sefer which seems to deal with this question at length: https://www.sefaria.org/On_Resurrection_of_the_Dead.13.2.1?lang=bi&with=About&lang2=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears this was Rabbi Tavi's chidush, i.e. he deduced a new additional reference to the resurrection. so read it as "here's [another] response.."

the talmud in sanhedrin 92a where this also appears lists several different possible responses (see bottom of 91b).

Likewise, he is coming to explain that the verse is not just a comparison but a Kal V'Chomer as explained [here](http://dafyomi.co.il/sanhedrin/points/sn-ps-092.htm)

Comment: Thanks, Ray! Where in Sanhedrin are you referring to? My source for this was Berakhot 15b.

Comment: @ShimonbM updated